# Using Hoeffding's inequality on sum of uniform variables

Tags: uniform-distribution, probability-inequalities, hoeffdings-inequality

I have the following problem:

$X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. $\sim U(-3,5)$ continuous uniform variables in the support between -3 and 5. $S := X_1 + ... + X_n$.

I need to use Hoeffding's inequality to find an $N$ such that $\forall n \ge N$:
$$
P(S > n^2 + 0.2n) < 0.1
$$

Now I tried to use the [generalized Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables) given as:
$$
P(S - E(S) \ge t) \le e^{\frac{-2t^2}{\sum(b-a)^2}}
$$

Now, $E(S) = n$, so I subtract it from both sides to get $P(S - n > n^2 - 0.8n) \le e^{\frac{-2(n^2-0.8n)^2}{64n}} < 0.1$

Now the math is really ugly, but eventually I can find that numerically $n > 4.7...$, i.e. that $N \ge 5$.

But I'm not sure this makes sense - as $P = 0$ for any $N \ge 5$, and also for $N = 4$ I think the probability of $P(X_1 +... X_4 > 16.8)$ is less than 0.1.

So I'm guessing I'm wrong - but can someone help me find the mistake?

Comment: Is it implausible that the goal of the exercise is to show the weakness of Hoeffding's inequality?

Comment: @Forgottenscience could be...